# aura 2.0.0 without powerpill?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, aur

I recently updated my `aura` package to 2.0.0 ([aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/aura-git/)). While reading the changelog ([here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aura-2.0.0/changelog)) i noticed the `powerpill` support was dropped.

Can anyone tell my why this was done? Was it due to the overall "speed improvements"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PKGBUILD that ships with Aura](https://github.com/aurapm/aura/blob/master/aura/test/aura.PKGBUILD), powerpill is still an `optdepend`. Meaning you can still use it if you choose.

The version you link to, however, is the -git version in the AUR and, as far as I can tell, that maintainer has never included any optdepends in their PKGBUILD. You would have to ask them why they do it differently.